# ggplot frequency two lines across time (month year)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to graph frequency of speeches over time (time is yy-mmm), and I would like the graph to have two lines -- one for democrats and one for republicans. It should be straightforward, but I can't get it to work. Below is a sample data set and sample code for what has not worked.

```
myDataSet1 <- as.data.frame(cbind ("dates" = c("13-Jan", "15-Jan", "20-Jun", "13-May", 
"19-Dec"), "Party" = c("Republican", "Democrat", 
"Republican", "Democrat", "Democrat"), "Speeches" = c("2", "6", "9", "3", "6") ) )
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
ggplot(data = myDataSet1, mapping = aes(x = dates, y = Speeches, 
color = Party)) + geom_line()
```

I get this

```
error: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

EDIT --
The solution worked, but it gave me lines as well as bars. To fix it, someone suggested adding "str()" after the mutate pipe.

Here's the code I am running and having errors with:

```
myDataSet1 %>%
    mutate(Speeches = as.integer(as.character(Speeches)),
           dates = as.Date(paste0(dates, "-2022"), "%y-%b-%d")) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = dates, y = court_rhetoric, color = Party)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%y-%b")
```

The error it gives me is:

> Error in `fortify()`:
> ! `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval.
> Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?

I also tried it piping into the ggplot and I get a different error:
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Your "dates" and "Speeches" variables are characher format. You need to convert them to Date and numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coerce `Speeches` to numeric and `dates` to a real date class. Then plot and set the date labels to the wanted, original format.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

myDataSet1 %>%
  mutate(Speeches = as.integer(as.character(Speeches)),
         dates = as.Date(paste0(dates, "-01"), "%y-%b-%d")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dates, Speeches, color = Party)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%y-%b")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! There's just one issue. Actually, the dates are backwards. So, in the case of my sample data 13-Jan actually refers to January of 2013 (as opposed to January 13), so it's giving me errors. I am assuming this is something in this part of the code "%d-%b-%Y"  but I am not sure how to fix it. Could you help? Thank you again!

Comment: Because when I try to switch the date to the correct format, I get this errorError in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number

Comment: @ertey Done, see now.

Comment: Actually, there's something else wrong. It does not look like yours when I plot it. Instead, it shows both bars and geom lines. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @ertey Before plotting, pipe to `str()`. Like this: `myDataSet1 %>% mutate(Speeches = as.integer(as.character(Speeches)), dates = as.Date(paste0(dates, "-01"), "%y-%b-%d")) %>% str()`. Are `Speeches` numeric and `dates` a Date?

Comment: I get this - Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval.
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @ertey Run the code in my previous comment *without* piping to ggplot.

Comment: Speeches is integer, and dates a date. I ran it without piping to the ggplot and I get this error. Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval.
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @ertey That error comes from ggplot. Can you update the question with the code you are running?

Comment: I updated it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @ertey The code you posted now is very different from the code in my answer. You have a `paste0` instruction with `"-2022"` when it is `"-01"` and you have `y = court_rhetoric` instead of `Speeches`. Run ***my*** code and see what it outputs, please.